# Windows doubleclick duration

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click

Is it possible to know how much millisecond the double click event is fired?
I want to fire my own double clic event from the click event and I would like to use the same value the user set in the mouse control panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx)

I'd also be curious as to know what you are really trying to accomplish here.  There may be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm triggering this DoubleClick event myself watching the timespan between two Click event because it doesn't fire... My control is a ToolStripButton but I could reproduce the problem on standard button. I'm wondering if the fact to develop using Visual Studio on bootcamp has to do with the problem but the double clic is well catch in the mouse control panel...